# Is it possible to assign a variable in a while loop?

Tags: java

I'm looking for a way to use scanner in a while loop, without advancing twice.

```
String desc = "";
while (!scanner.next().equals("END")) {
    desc = desc + scanner.next();
}
```

As you can see, when `scanner.next()` is called in the while loop's condition and inside of the while loop itself. I want it to advance the scanner only once. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: you looking to transform while loop to for loop?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assign variable in Java while-loop conditional?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264054/assign-variable-in-java-while-loop-conditional)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You should also check that the `Scanner` has more tokens in its input

```
String desc = "";
String next = null;
while (scanner.hasNext() && !(next = scanner.next()).equals("END")) {
    desc = desc + next;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    String temp = "";
    do {
        desc = desc + temp;
        temp = scanner.next();
    } while(!temp.equals("END"))
```

You can use a do-while for post loop condition checking