# Is it possible to declare a variable within a Java while conditional?

Tags: java, while-loop

In Java it is possible to declare a variable in the initialization part of a `for`-loop:

```
for ( int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
  // do something (with i)
}
```

But with the `while` statement this seems not to be possible.

Quite often I see code like this, when the conditional for the while loop needs to be updated after every iteration:

```
List<Object> processables = retrieveProcessableItems(..); // initial fetch
while (processables.size() > 0) {
    // process items
    processables = retrieveProcessableItems(..); // update
}
```

Here on stackoverflow I found at least [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10264076/4791599) to prevent the duplicate code of fetching the processable items:

```
List<Object> processables;
while ((processables = retrieveProcessableItems(..)).size() > 0) {
    // process items
}
```

But the variable still has to be declared outside the while-loop.

So, as I want to keep my variable scopes clean, is it possible to declare a variable within the while conditional, or is there some other solution for such cases?

Comment: There is a `do-while` loop which sounds like a good candidate in this case. The declaration will have to stay outside of the loop, but at least you will have only one assignment instead of two.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak - So, where would be the difference to my final `while` example above?

Comment: Cleaner code. It wouldn't have assignment hidden in the boolean expression.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak Could you provide an answer with an example? Right now I'm unable to imagine how you mean that.

Comment: There is no way to do such a thing, but you can try to use stream API to make your code functional style

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can write a `while` loop using a `for` loop:

```
while (condition) { ... }
```

is the same as

```
for (; condition; ) { ... }
```

since all three bits in the brackets of the [basic for statement declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1) are optional:

```
BasicForStatement:
    for ( [ForInit] ; [Expression] ; [ForUpdate] ) Statement
```

Similarly, you can just rewrite your `while` loop as a `for` loop:

```
for (List<Object> processables;
     (processables = retrieveProcessableItems(..)).size() > 0;) {
  // ... Process items.
}
```

Note that some static analysis tools (e.g. eclipse 4.5) might demand that an initial value is assigned to `processables`, e.g. `List<Object> processables = null`. This is incorrect, according to JLS; my version of `javac` does not complain if the variable is left initially unassigned.

Comment: Nicked your last idea. UV for sake of a clear conscience.

Comment: Sorry, the for-loop reintroduces the duplicate-code problem, since it is necesarry to update the `processables` in the *increment* part of the statement: `for (List<Object> processables = retrieveProcessableItems(..);
     processables.size() > 0; processables = retrieveProcessableItems(..))`

Comment: There ought to be no need for the initial assignment to `null`?

Comment: @MarkusMitterauer then assign it in the `Expression`.

Comment: @Bathsheba you're right. I've never actually tried that before; had to try it to convince myself!

Comment: I'm very sure, the [Expression] is evaluated at least once (unless an exception is thrown in the [ForInit])

Comment: @Bathsheba sorry, I wasn't meaning to sound like I disbelieved you :) Like I say, I've just never had cause to declare a variable without initialization in the [ForInit]. Tried it, checked the spec; of course, you are right.

Comment: @Bathsheba - Yes, that would be possible. Except for the drawback that I now get either an *"Null pointer access: The variable processables can only be null at this location"* or *"The local variable processables may not have been initialized"* warning/error depending on initializing of the variable with `null` or not. (Eclipse 4.5 / Java 8)

Comment: To me that's a defect in your IDE: it *ought* to know that something is *always* assigned to the variable before its contents are read. `= null` it is then.

Comment: @Bathsheba I've moved it out as a separate point, so it's easier to read the "not in error" answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

No it's not possible.

It doesn't really make too much sense either: unlike a `for` loop where you can set up the initial state of the "looping variable", in a `while` loop you test the value of an *existing* variable, akin to the *conditional check* of the `for` loop.

Of course, if you're concerned about variables "leaking" into other parts of your code, you could enclose the whole thing in an extra scope block:

```
{
   /*declare variable here*/
   while(...){...}
}
```

Alternatively, convert the `while` loop into a `for` loop.

Comment: I think is better & cleaner than the accepted answer. Far more readable.

Comment: @rpax While it might be cleaner, I just see it as workaround for my question. I knew of course that I can artificially restrict the scope of a variable with curly braces, but that was not what I asked for. The other answer dwelled more on the alternative solution with `for` which actually can substitute a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Make a do/while:

```
String value;
do {
    value = getValue();
    ...your processing
} while (value != null && !value.isEmpty());
```