# Syntax error on token "double" within if statement body

Tags: java

When I try to run this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double salary = 10.1;

    if (salary >= 100.3)
        double number = salary * 10;
    else
        double number = salary * 20;

}
```

I get the following errors:

> Syntax error on token "double", delete this token

and that both:

> number cannot be resolved to a variable

Now the code is **purposely bad**, as it is a question where we have to state everything that's wrong with it.

As far as I understand, it's best practice to not declare the same variable twice and it's best to always use curly brackets; but why does the `double number = salary * 10;` and `double number = salary * 20;` cause an issue if curly brackets aren't used? I would've thought that would still compile and run correctly (it works if the brackets are used).

Comment: A declaration is not allowed in an `if` statement without braces. This is because, if you can only have one statement in the `if`, a declaration is useless. The scope ends immediately.

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38766891/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-variable-within-a-java-while-conditional

Comment: You can, of course, do `double number = salary >= 100.3 ? salary * 10 : salary * 20;` or even `double number = salary * (salary >= 100.3 ? 10 : 20);`

Comment: @bcsb1001 it would not be entirely useless: `int a = someFunctionWithSideEffect(a = veryExpensiveMethod(), a);` is (otherwise) legal (perhaps surprisingly); here, `a` can be used as a temporary variable to avoid recomputing the parameter. But this isn't exactly sensible code, and if you really want to use it, you could always just wrap it in braces. Just pointing out you *could* use a variable declaration in an if to some vaguely practical end.

Answer (score 4):

Because it violates the Java grammar.  The JLS [defines `if` statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9) as follows:

> ```
> IfThenStatement:
>     if ( Expression ) Statement
> ```

So it's expecting a `Statement`.  Curly braces denote a `Block`, and a [`Block` **is** a `Statement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-Statement).  However, a variable declaration is **not** a `Statement`.<sup>1</sup>

This is intuitively sensible behaviour - if you *could* declare a variable here, it would be useless, as it would immediately go out of scope.

---

<sub>1. Confusingly, variable declarations are referred to as `LocalVariableDeclarationStatement`s in the JLS.  However, that's not a kind of `Statement` as far as the language grammar is concerned.</sub>

Comment: In what sense aren't they a statement? Sure, they're not a `Statement`, but they are a `BlockStatement`.

Comment: @AndyTurner - Maybe formatting my answer would help?  A `BlockStatement` is not a `Statement`, and `if` is expecting a `Statement`.

Comment: yes, I think that backticks would make it clearer. I think the "confusingly" here is that the spec calls it a `Statement`, even though other statement types are not included in that.